# How to print a list of characters in python without brackets, commas, or quotes?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a random password generator based on three parameters. Number of letters, symbols, and numbers. I would like to use a list but when I print it the brackets, quotes, and commas show up. If I enter a pre-filled list eg. `["1", "g", "&", "0"]`, `print (*password, sep='')` works as expected. Not when the list is randomly populated though. Is there another function I can use?

Do not mind the `new_let`, `new_num`, `new_sym` in my for loops. Was just trying something out.

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6zxg.png)

Comment: Hey there, welcome to stackoverflow! In the future, please include your code in text form instead of an image and add the appropriate language tag :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your example code is that `password` is not a list of characters but a list of lists. Use `random.choice()` instead of `random.choices()`. The latter returns a list.

There is no reason for your solution not to work on a randomly generated list

```
import random
l=["1", "g", "&", "0",'d','2']
print(*[random.choice(l) for i in range(5)], sep='')

01dg2
```